# Load a array from CSV using php and index first row and first column

Tags: php, csv

im been looking in to php array_column and array_map but i still dont get it!.

This is the code i use for loading my CSV

```
    <?PHP
        $row = 1;
        $faq = array(); //define the main array.

        if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                $row++;

                for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                }
                $faq[] = $data; //add the row to the main array.
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    ?>
```

And this is is how i output the data:

```
echo $faq[1][13];
```

So the [1] is the row and the [13] is the column.

But if that info is not longer on the row [1] but i still want to finds that data.
So if we say column and row 0 is a ID/header and i could write

```
echo $faq['printing']['Hash_tag'];
```

['printing'] = would mean the row it finds that word on column 0

['Hash_tag'] = would mean the column "13" where it finds that on the top row.

For sure this is a duplicate but i been looking in to this for a long time and im almost giving up as i cant figure it out.

Comment: something is wrong in this code. There is a for block that does nothing. Please check that

Comment: It works! In the way i already specified! Without "index" of the first row/column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a very small template - there is no error checking (as in your code) so please add it as you see fit...

```
$fh = fopen("a.txt", "r");
$header = fgetcsv($fh);
$faq = [];
while ( $data = fgetcsv($fh))   {
    $faq [ $data[0] ] = array_combine($header, $data);
}

print_r($faq);
```

Run with the file

```
tag1,tag2
a,1
b,2
r,t
```

Gives the output

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [tag1] => a
            [tag2] => 1
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [tag1] => b
            [tag2] => 2
        )

    [r] => Array
        (
            [tag1] => r
            [tag2] => t
        )

)
```

Comment: echo $faq['tag1']['a']; still dont show A, or im i writing something wrong?

Comment: I would have thought you wanted $faq['a']['tag1'] - as 'a' is the value in column 0 and 'tag1' was the label in the first row for the first column.  Or I may have got it the wrong way round.

Comment: maybe i wrote it wrong i tried both ways.. And i still dont get the any output

Comment: What does the `print_r` give?  This should show the output as I gave and with that - `echo $faq['a']['tag1'];` gives `a`.

Comment: That's most likely a JSON file.

Comment: thats the CSV showing as a JSON only,  so you could see the fields a bit better then a CSV :) im working on a JSON thingy for this also.. but one thing at the time..

Comment: OK - if your loading that data - then the labels from my test file won't work - try `echo $faq['Intro_Title']['Intro'];`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hm06vv (i tried both ways, and they dont work, but printing them all works).. i dont know im i missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160937/discussion-between-nigel-ren-and-user1296114).